# "." nor "f" work to viewport zoom on a selected object

Tags: interface

I need to have a zoom on selected object working. Old tutorials state it's the <kbd>numpad period</kbd>, my keyboard doesn't have a numpad. I saw a post saying that the function has been remapped to <kbd>F</kbd> on 2.8, but that doesn't work either. I can't find the command in the keymap settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hotkey is called *View Selected*.

[image: hotkey]

Comment: yeay, that helped. For some reason that key wasn't working on a keyboard with no number pad, nor did changing the input to Emulate numpad allowed it to work.

Comment: This keyboard shortcut only works with a numpad. Emulating the number pad only works for the number keys 0 - 9. If this answer solved your question, consider marking it as accepted by ticking the check mark on the top left of the answer.

Comment: "View selected" changed to "Frame Selected" with Blender 2.83. (https://developer.blender.org/rBe4eede83187d6e4f784491532a0887d4f8c9ba31)